# Delete Firefox Active Logins

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, python-3.4

I am using Selenium Firefox WebDriver through a script in Python3.4.

Is there a way (keyboard shortcut / parameter in about:config / firefox plugin / selenium command / other) to do in the script the following action that I usually can do manually on a Firefox browser?

> CTRL+SHIFT+DEL and delete **only** active logins

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
As explained [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=remove-recent-browsing-search-and-download-history#w_what-things-are-included-in-my-history) the above action clears the HTTP Authentication Cache, unfortunately the following JS only apply to IE.

> document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");

Doing the following in Firefox is not the same as manually doing the action (because does not solve another problem I met, which is solved by CTRL+SHIFT+DEL and delete active logins)

> https://foobar@www.example.com/

Any idea?

Comment: Try driver.quit(), it will delete the history, cookies and passwords.

Comment: It is exactly what I was doing till now; but doing that decrease a lot the performances of the script. I would like to keep firefox open if it is possible..

Comment: Selenium doesn't provide the methods for this task. Your best and only option is probably to work with an add-on.

Comment: Thank you! I have noticed that with selenium I can run pieces of JS code. Unfortunately I am completely new to JS, is it possible to clear HTTP Authentication cache with JS? if possible, would it be the same as CTRL+SHIFT+DEL delete active logins?

Comment: I could try to delete the cookies with some Javascript, but it's kind of tricky. See by yourself on SO, the question has already been answered.

Comment: Wait, I have alredy tried to delete cookies (with selenium) but that does not solve the problem: CTRL+SHIFT+DEL 'delete cookies' is not the same of CTRL+SHIFT+DEL 'delete active logins'.